# What is the difference between entitlement and license key?

Tags: licensing, entitlements

Maybe it is more about business model than technical details.

It seemed to me that license key is giving users access to a product, while entitlement allows users to use some sort of service (like 2GB storage a month)?

Comment: As you say - it's more about the business model and it's therefore off-topic here.

Comment: It is more important for me to get the help and share the question with people, than thinking about whether it is off topic. But thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are part of the same hierarchy of Customer Software Management.

At the point of sale for a software product the customer has purchased a license key and **explicitly** (with the specific EULA details he agrees to) gets the immediate benefits and responsibilities of that contract/license key.

But the customer also **implicitly** 'inherits' any add on privileges and benefits (entitlements) of that software sale too... such as future free versions within a time period, volume licensing, discount pricing.. which he may or may not make use of.

Further research on this... Safenet company...
http://www.safenet-inc.com/software-monetization/sentinel-entitlement-management/